# Is the function $f(x) = (x^2, \sin x)$ onto or one-to-one? 

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have $f(x)=(x^2,\sin x)$ defined by $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Can we show that this function is onto or one-to-one?

Comment: Draw a graph...

Comment: If you stop and *think* about the function for a little, you should find both questions very easy. In particular, a graph will answer the first one immediately.

Comment: Does it *seem* like it should be onto? For the second one, what happens if $x=\pm\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is not onto:
It's $y$ coordinate is limited by $1$, since $\sin (x) \leq \ 1 \  \forall x$.

It is not one-to-one:
take $ x = -2\pi $ and $y = 2\pi $.   $f(x) = (4\pi^2, \sin(-2\pi))$  $\ =$ $ (4\pi^2, 0)$.
$f(y) = (4\pi^2, \sin(2\pi)) = (4\pi^2, 0) = f(x)$

Comment: @Asaf, Thanks for fighting for a good cos. :) [Sorry, couldn't resist it.]

Answer (score 1):

$((-2 \pi)^2, \sin (-2 \pi)) = ((2 \pi)^2, \sin (2 \pi))$